# The meaning of "complaint" in this python tutorial

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Could you please tell me what is the meaning of "hence complaint" in this sentence:

> We’ve brought back a positional argument, hence the complaint.

[Combining Positional and Optional arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html#combining-positional-and-optional-arguments)

Thank you

Comment: It refers to the error message about square being missing.

Comment: The question in the title and body don't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computer people tend to anthropomorphize computers- to think of them as if they were human. When a compiler detects an error and displays an error message, they feel that the computer is complaining about their mistake.